# Passport Js custom callback function not calling next middleware

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to authenticate a user with custom callback in passport js. I have written my code based on the passport documentation.

```
router.post("/signin/email", function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate("email-local", function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send("err");
    }
    if (!user) {
        return res.send(info);
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        next(user);
    });
    })(req, res, next),
        UsersController.getToken;
});
```

I want to pass the user to the next middleware i.e `UsersController.getToken` ,but it is not being passed. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Passport will add the user data to `req.user` after login is called so you don't need to pass it with next.
I would recommend simplifying the `req.logIn` call to the following:

```js
return req.logIn(user, next)
```

Then within you `UsersController.getToken` middleware you can access the user data through the `req` object.